# Where is Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Mouse Wheel discrete rotation in 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I can't find this in 2.8 and it was really useful.

For instance in 2.79 you could Ctrl-Alt-Wheel to roll rotate the view based on your current. The only way I could do this in 2.8 was with the numpad 4,8,6 keys, which isn't nearly as handy.

Comment: In Edit>Preferences>Keymap you can choose (at the top-left corner) Blender 27X and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, changing to 2.7x layout dose fix it but i want to keep the rest 2.8.  also in 2.8 controls it is listed,  holding down `control` + `shift` also says dolly on the bottom of the screen in both 2.8 and 2.7 layouts in blender 2.8 release candidate.

i have found the python files responsible for the shortcuts
exporting blender layout makes a .py calling for a different .py
exporting 2.7x layout makes a lot of changes to the same py as listed before

```
 also first time posting on stack
```

[[image]]

Comment: I was able to find the orbit control under View, then right click and change shortcut for each orbit direction to the same as 2.79... so I guess problem solved!

Comment: "i have found the python files responsible for the shortcuts exporting blender layout makes a .py calling for a different .py exporting 2.7x layout makes a lot of changes to the same py as listed before" Man, it's hardly comprehensible.